# Ribbonrow in modal dialog

Tags: branding

The modal dialogs uses the customized system master page. In this master page we can see that there is a div with id s4-ribbonrow which has display:none css applied. Following this line is a securityTrimmedControl which checks for AddAndCustomizePages permissions for a user and make the div visible. The code snippet can be seen below.

```
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr" style="display:none">
 <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2"
 runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
     </script> </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Inside the div s4-ribbonrow is another div which has the actual controls bound to ribbon. The id for this div is s4-ribboncont, this div has a sharepoint control in it  SharePoint:SPRibbon which has the ribbon data.

From my observations by looking at the html that is rendered in the modal dialog it is evident that for a **normal user** s4-ribboncont is not bound but for the **admin user** this div has additional data bound to it.

I am stuck to make the ribbon visible for the normal user with proper permissions.

What I have tried

- Changing permission string at Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl. Tried with all the possible permission string available.
- Changing permission at SharePoint:SPRibbon. Tried with many possible permission strings.

  - Changing the permission at the child controls of the SPRibbon individually
    None of these changes had any effect on the dialog box.

I even tried the same steps with rconline.master also, but to vain nothing happened.

My gut feeling is we need to use permissions **ManageLists** also with the **AddAndCustomizePages**, but did not work as thought.

I feel that there is some thing very small that I am missing to get to a solution,  Help me understand how is the data ribbon row can be made visible for normal users. 
I am not the one who developed this master page, this was done by some one else who is no longer with us.

I have attached the screent shot to illustrate what I am talking about.
For Admin it comes like below[image]

Expecting the same for normal user who has edit permissions on the same page, since add itme is enabled he can add items but ribbon is not visible
[image]

Can some one please help me. I am stuck here.